# No primes in $f(n) = n(n+3)/2$ except 2 and 5

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I prove that the sequence

$f(n) = n(n+3)/2 = 0, 2, 5, 9, 14, 20, 27, 35, 44, ...$

does not contain primes except $2$ and $5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then $f(n) = \frac{n}{2}\cdot (n+3)$, which is composite (since both factors are integers greater than $1$) for $n \geq 4$.

If $n$ is odd, then $f(n) = n \cdot \frac{n+3}2$, which is composite for $n \geq 3$

Answer (score 2):

One of $n$ and $n+3$ is even, so either $(n/2)(n+3)$ is a factorization of $f(n)$, or $n ( (n+3)/2 )$ is a factorization. Neither factor is $1$ provided $n$ is at least $3$. Hence for $n > 2$, $f(n)$ is composite.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that none of those numbers are prime, all you need to find is the non-trivial divisor.

**Hint:** Prove that one $(n+3)/2$ or $n/2$ is a divisor, one of them actually isn't even integer.